# Drupal 7: How can I allow a user role to upload a file via the WYSIWYG editor?

Tags: drupal

I created a new user role. I noticed that its WYSIWYG editor doesn't have the upload file/browse option for hyper links. I've checked the permissions and I cannot locate anything that works.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [LinkIt](https://drupal.org/project/LINKIT) to add an hyperlink chooser in the WYSIWYG editor. IMCE bridge module is used for files.

Comment: Found the IMCE module and perms settings... right after I posted this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I have used the [IMCE Module](https://drupal.org/project/imce) for this.

> IMCE is an image/file uploader and browser that supports personal
>   directories and quota.

and it has the ability to integrate to WYSIWYG.